# Any method to calculate the distance between an infinite line and an axis-aligned arc?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have a infinite line in 3D, let's say its end points as $A$ and $B$ (long distance between $A$ and $B$), and an axis-aligned arc, let's say its center as $C$, start point as $S$ and end point as $E$. How do we calculate the distance between them?

Or the arc may be a helix?

My question at **Stack Overflow** is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226601/any-method-to-calculate-the-distance-between-an-infinite-line-and-an-axis-aligne):

Here is a picture for my question.

[image]

**Arc or helix is in the $xy$ plane as the picture shows.**

The line direction is show by the $xyz$ axes.

The red point represent the line perpendicular to the screen.

The left and center picture show arc condition and the right one is helix.

Anyone has an idea with it?